Tension of rope over frictionless edge obstructing block
Consider the diagram below. All corners are assumed to have no friction. Is it true that the tension throughout the rope is equal in all sections? The section over the edge of the building, the section between the edge of the building and the back right corner of the block where the rope turns around it, and finally the section between the back right corner of the block and the eyebolt anchor point.
Maybe another way I could reframe my question is, can the angles around these edges influence the tension in the different sections? For example, the angle between the rope and the block is not the same on the load-side as the angle between the rope and the block on the anchor-side. Does that matter?


If you don't consider friction edge angle don't affect tension. It will be uniform throughout its length.

Thankyou for your help @Fire

As long as all surfaces are considered frictionless and the rope is considered non extensible, the tension would theoretically be constant throughout.
IMO this is an example of “pushing the envelope”. Normally, at least the surfaces are rounded.

All corners are assumed to have no friction. This is quite an assumption!

I'm pretty sure a lot of text books have this assumption in it when trying to simplify models for pedagogical purposes. As you can see, I was trying to learn if angles have any bearing on tension regardless of whether there is friction or not. It makes perfect sense. Maybe you should take your issue up with publishers of physics text books.  @Farcher

@Bucephalus I agree with you but that makes the answer to your question rather straight forward.

Thanks for your response @Farcher . Maybe you can give me some more learned insight into David Quinn's comment about bisection of angle, at my original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4945410/force-of-a-tensioned-rope-on-an-obstructing-block?noredirect=1#comment10574164_4945410

@Bucephalus I have added a comment to your post to explain why the angles must be equal.

Thanks @Farcher I have read that response. How does your response relate to this sentence I have asked here in this question? For example, the angle between the rope and the block is not the same on the load-side as the angle between the rope and the block on the anchor-side. Have I created for myself the illusion that the angle between the two tensions in this diagram is not bisected where in fact, right at the point of the corner, the normal force is indeed bisecting the angle between the two tensions?

@Bucephalus The direction of a normal to an ideal corner is an interesting concept.  With you two bits of rope, either side of the corner, you can always choose the normal to be one which bisects the angle.

Thanks @Farcher . To futher understand this was the point of my interrogation.

I would consider each bent part a point of interest. Starting at the last bend before the hanging mass, let's fix the rope on the edge and calculate the tension for this segment. Call it $|T_2|=mg$.
Next, the kink at the block. Pretend the rope is fixed at this point. This time, let's simplify by replacing the edge and hanging mass with a constant force of $T_2$. See where this is going? This tension is just $T_1 = T_2$.
The rope is not stretching, sliding, or moving, so the presence of friction does not matter. This is an essential aspect of your question. In the static case, Any corner perfectly steers the rope's tension from the start to the hanging mass. If you had a knob that increased the static friction of your system, and you turned it all the way up so that it takes more than the tension to make the string start moving, then you effectively have three separate segments of string, each held at the original tension.
Start letting things move, and this becomes a totally different question.

Thanks for your response @ABetheGammow
